# not-read-only DataGridView, but don't show input in datagridview after leaving, only show programmatical input

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

In my DataGridView users are able to input data. The DataGridView automatically changes its content when one of the properties of a correspondent list of objects changes with the help of events.

Now I want to give the DataGridView the following behavior: when the user inserts data, and then leaves the cell, the input should be validated. If the validation gives a positive result, the input is saved to an object. The datagridview should then show the input value in the correct format (eg. for a date).

I can make this work: the events between the list of objects and the datagridview can manage this.

The problem is: If the validation gives a negative result, the previous cell value should be restored.

I tried to use DataGridView.CellValidating event, but this doesn't work. What should I do?

SOLVED: I used e.Cancel. This doesn't really do what I thought it promissed. When I use DataGridView1.CancelEdit(), it works like I wanted.

Comment: Why don't you bind to a DataTable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used e.Cancel. This doesn't really do what I thought it promissed. When I use DataGridView1.CancelEdit(), it works like I wanted.